# Inserting multiple input values as different rows in a different table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am working on a single product page. There are `colors` table in the database to define colors of each product. It looks like this;

```html
| key | product_id | color |
+-----+------------+-------+
|   1 |          4 | black |
|   2 |          7 | red   |
|   3 |          8 | blue  |
|   4 |          8 | black |
+-----+------------+-------+
```

I insert the product via `productController.php`. No problem with this. Moreover, I want to insert colors to their own table with the same auto increment id. As you can imagine, there are multiple inputs for each color in the form. What is the right method and which functions should I use?

A simplified view of the form is below.

```html
<form>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="productname" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Colors</label>
    <div class="controls" id="color">
      <input type="text" name="colors[]" />
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addcolor"> + Add</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Product</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

After INSERTING into products table, get the last insert id

```
$last_id = $db->insert_id;

$sql="";
$colours=$_POST['colours'];
foreach($colours as $colour)
{
    $sql.="INSERT INTO colours_table (product_id,color) values ('$last_id','$color');"
}

$db->query($sql);
```

Of course take all precautions against sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your DB structure like

```
color_master

| colorId | colorName |
+---------+-----------+
|     1   |   black   |
|     2   |   red     |
|     3   |   blue    |
+---------+-----------+

product_color

| product_color_id | product_id | color_id |
+------------------+------------+----------+
|        1         |     4      |    1     |
|        2         |     7      |    2     |
|        3         |     8      |    3     |
|        4         |     4      |    3     |
+------------------+------------+----------+
```

I suggest you to use `<select>` with `multiple` selection option.

```
 <select name="color[]" multiple></select>
```

at the PHP end you will get the Color array in post and you can then insert in your database

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I should use text inputs as there will be unlimited number of colors. Actually `color` is just an example among a lot of inputs.